# Docusign (Drag and Drop signature placeholder feature need to develop in my website)

Tags: docusignapi

https://i.stack.imgur.com/khcVt.jpg

Docusign webportal gives drag and drop feature for signature,etc in their website. I want to build same drag and drop feature in my website

Comment: Could you please specify what you have done so far? You will usually get help if you show some initiative.

Comment: I have integrated whole api via pdf tagging process

Comment: Do you want to plugin that page on your website, so that sender can do drag and drop on your website instead of logging into DocuSign website?

Comment: @AmitKBist  - exactly i want to integrate that feature into my website

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Drag and Drop feature, you need to use below endpoint

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
```

More details available at:

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/

Comment: how this can be implemented in php sdk
my skype id is imran_phpdeveloper
Thanks for your time

Comment: You can check example at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php, funtion name is `testCreateEmbeddedSendingView($testConfig)`

Comment: - Let me explain you in detail.

Comment: Let me explain you in detail.
We are developing a rental website, where property owner submit a lease agreement with rental signing location via docusign API features with in our website. 

Currently we are using Docusign placeholder feature, but owner wants to create drag and drop feature. I am stuck at this pts for last month. 

Currently we are using this php library. 
https://github.com/docusign/devcenter-quickstarts/blob/master/1-SignatureRequest/SignatureRequest.php

Please help me i am in big trouble.

Comment: So owner is interested in doing the drag and drop of DocuSign tabs on the lease agreement on your website directly, so that they can on their own put DocuSign tabs on the document where ever they want?

Comment: @ Amit K Bist  -  yes

Comment: -yes when owner upload the document to our website, then owner want to place tag *drag and drop feature* via api similar to Docusign api

Comment: Then why are you not planning to show embedded Sending view as I posted on my answer, using embedded Sending view, DocuSign will give you a URL, then open that URL and ask customer to complete the tagging (drag and drop)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! wow

@ Amit K Bist  - Create Embed Signing View is not redirecting to my webite, can you please help how to do that. 

I am trying to send set ReturnUrl  in function testCreateEmbeddedSendingView($testConfig), but 

$return_url_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ReturnUrlRequest();
$return_url_request->setReturnUrl($testConfig->getReturnUrl());

Comment: I hope you are generating Embedded Sending View on a draft envelope only, I did not run the testCreateEmbeddedSendingView() php code but code looks fine to me and it should work as expected, when sender completes the tagging and click "Send", then flow should redirect the browser to the returnUrl set in the "createSenderView" method.